# How can i detect whether a tableViewCell is **current** first or last cell of all cells being displayed

Tags: uitableview, detect

I have a UITableView with many cells that it cannot display all of them at one time.

For example, the table's height is 220 (44*5), and the height of a single cell is 44.

and there is altogether 10 cells, so I have to scroll the table to display cells.

My question is, how can I find if a cell is **current** first and last cell of current displayed tableView,

since I want to always make some special effects for the first and last cell being displayed at any time.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Yes,WhatEver you want,you can get with NSIndexPath.get your cell IndexPath and make effects.

Comment: Thanks, but what I meant is that I know how indexPath works, but now I want to find out whether a cell of some indexPath is the **currently** first displayed cell in the limited table of the screen. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Whenever you acroll table,reloaddata get call that time, you will come to know which indexpath cell is going to be displayed.